# How to add HTML component to React.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

App.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Carousel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/materialize.min.css">
    </link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="App.css">
    </link>
</head>
<div class="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src={require("./1.png")} class="responsive-img"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src={require("./2.png")} class="responsive-img"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src={require("./3.png")} class="responsive-img"></img>
    </div>

    <script src="./js/materialize.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        const small = document.querySelector('.carousel');
        var inst = M.Carousel.init(small, {});
        inst.dist(50);
    </script>
</div>

</html>
```

App.js

```js
import React from 'react';

var perf = require('./App.html');

class App extends React.Component {
   render(){
      return (
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: perf }} ></div>
      );
   }
}
export default App;
```

Can someone please help me with how can I add the HTML file in my JS file and run the HTML file via my JS file. I have made a carousel using materialize in HTML, but I am unable to either write the very code in JS hence, if possible can someone please help me either with converting the HTML file to a JS file, or how can I import the HTML file in my JS file.

Comment: Why don't you create `<Carousel/>` component and put all the necessary markup and dependencies over there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `react-create-app` template and the basic `html` (head, meta) things are already in place, Just modify the `src` dir to meet you needs.

for example the `index.js` would be something like this,

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css'; // For Your CSS file

class App extends React.Component {
   render(){
      return (
        <div class="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src={require("./1.png")} class="responsive-img"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src={require("./2.png")} class="responsive-img"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src={require("./3.png")} class="responsive-img"></img>
    </div>
      );
   }
}
export default App;
```

if your need to change the base `html` you can do so in the public dir.

#### EDIT: (For the dependencies)

As you use `materialize-css`, You can use that by installing `materialize-css@next` as a dependency using `npm` with this cmd `npm install materialize-css@next`

More info about installing can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62825659/reordering-elements-in-react-without-causing-them-to-rerender)

Source: https://materializecss.com/getting-started.html

Comment: Hi aXuser264, thanks for your response, but i am actually using a dependency named "Materialize", which you can see in my HTML, file named <link> and in <script> portion, you sure this would work out without adding them in js file. ?

Comment: @RankJay updated the question, check out &&  please mark as answer if it helped

Answer (score 3):

you can simply insert all off your html code in App.js file, reactjs doesn't require any .html file. just follow below code, hope you can understand it.
i simply put all HTML code into parent div of App.js.

```
import React from 'react';

var perf =require('./App.html');

class App extends React.Component {
   render(){
      return (
        <div>
            <div class="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src={require("./1.png")} class="responsive-img"></img>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src={require("./2.png")} class="responsive-img"></img>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src={require("./3.png")} class="responsive-img"></img>
                </div>  
             </div>
        </div>      
      );
      }
      }
    export default App;
```

Comment: Hi Fazal, thanks for your response, but i am actually using a dependency named "Materialize", which you can see in my HTML, file named <link> and in <script> portion, you sure this would work out without adding them in js file. ?

Comment: For this you have to add the dependency  package of "Materialize". After adding this package i am sure it will work.