# Reordering elements in React without causing them to rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I'm animating SVG with React, and I have have a few SVG elements that get rotated and reordered in JSX to change their stacking order. (SVG doesn't have a `z-index` property, so the elements need to be reordered manually.) My JSX looks like:

```
<svg>
  <g>
    <Rect key={'rect0'} />
    <Rect key={'rect1'} />
    <Rect key={'rect2'} />
    <Rect key={'rect3'} />
  </g>
</svg>
```

The SVG result looks like:

```
<svg>
  <g>
    <rect>
    <rect>
    <rect>
    <rect>
  </g>
</svg>
```

My problem is that when I change the order of these components, the rotated elements' rotation transition gets interrupted because the rotated elements are being re-rendered when their order gets changed. I need the rotation transition to be smooth. In some cases it may be possible to rotate a parent of the component instead, but in this case that feels like a hacky workaround. It would be preferable to have the component containing the rects have their rotation as part of their state.

I tried using `shouldComponentUpdate`, but rotation is in the state. If I compare state in shouldComponentUpdate to determine if the element should rotate, it re-renders, and if I always return false, the element doesn't rotate. I'll update my question with this. So I tried this:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return (nextState.rotation !== this.state.rotation);
}
```

Can this be done? Is there a straightforward solution?

I'll create a working example when I have spare time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use shouldComponentUpdate to decide if it should re-render.

```
class Elements extends Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    // This is just an example, but you can track the number of elements 
    // for instance and decide not to re-render if they're the same
    if (this.state.number === nextState.number) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <svg>
      <g>
        <Rect key={'rect0'} />
        <Rect key={'rect1'} />
        <Rect key={'rect2'} />
        <Rect key={'rect3'} />
     </g>
    </svg>
  }
}
```

In addition you could also consider deriving from PureComponent as it does a shallow check on props and state.

```
class Elements extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    return <svg>
      <g>
        <Rect key={'rect0'} />
        <Rect key={'rect1'} />
        <Rect key={'rect2'} />
        <Rect key={'rect3'} />
     </g>
    </svg>
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem here is that `rotation` is in the state. If I compare state in shouldComponentUpdate to determine if the element should rotate, it re-renders, and if I always return false, the element doesn't rotate. I'll update my question with this.

Comment: Can you post some of that code? Could you check for specific values in that state in that case?

Comment: There is only one value to check in my case, and that's rotation. When rotation has changed, I return true. That's when it interrupts the CSS transition. I'll post code when I have time to do that. It's crunch time currently.